# How use Search api saved searches module for Views?

Tags: views, search

I used module [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api), to search users and I used module [Search API saved searches](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_saved_searches) to save result after search. This problem is after searched then it not display "Save search" to save result after search.

Please see the image below.

[image]